CKAN package install does not see datapusher - Internal Server Error for url: http://127.0.0.1:8800/job
I installed CKAN on Ubuntu 22.04 using the package install instructions at https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.10/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html - including setting up API tokens, adding the plugins, etc
Everything worked as expected and I was able to use the web GUI to

create a new organisation
create a new dataset
add a TSV resource

However, when I click on the "DataStore" tab for this resource, it says:
Upload error: An Error occurred while sending the job: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://127.0.0.1:8800/job

I've checked that port 8800 is running uWSGI and accepting connections:
netstat -tulpn | grep 8800
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8800          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      43618/uwsgi

I checked /var/log/ckan/ckan-datapusher.stdout.log and it says:
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 43622|app: -1|req: -1/8] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 423 bytes} [Fri May 17 11:41:29 2024] POST /job => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 1)

And curl gives an error:
curl 127.0.0.1:8800
Internal Server Error

Does that mean uWSGI is running at port 8800 but datapusher is not running?
I don't know how uWSGI works and because this was a package install, I don't know how else to check what could be going wrong.
Any suggestions would be very welcome - thanks in advance!

i would suggest to try and use https://github.com/dathere/datapusher-plus/
it has option to use it as service (old datapusher) or as extension (1.0.0+) tag

Thanks, I will try and do that :-) I can see 1.0.1 released by you - thank you!
Not sure how to instal it as an extension (instructions on https://github.com/dathere/datapusher-plus/tree/1.0.1 seem to be for regular dev / production deployment, but if I get stuck I'll ask here
Thank you again!
